# Random 500 error - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

The website is running .Net 4 with MVC 3, Entity Framework, and Ninject. This error appears randomly and we are only able to detect it in load testing or production. Have not seen it once in development.

Stack trace:

```
   9/12/2012 12:35:19 PM: An item with the same key has already been added.
   HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://www.website.com/
   HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString: 
   HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /
   HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0E)
   HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress: 98.174.239.230
   StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntityEntryToDictionary(EntityEntry entry, EntityState state)
      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
      at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
      at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__NavCategoryPartial_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Website\Views\Shared\_NavCatPartial.cshtml:line 30
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
      at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
      at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
      at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.<Execute>b__4() in d:\Website\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 9
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClassb.<RenderSection>b__9(TextWriter tw)
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
      at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Website\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 57
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
      at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
      at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Feels like a context hanging around too long and being used by more than one asynchronous request. I think you should look at context life cycle management by Ninject.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? A project I'm on has a similar error.

Comment: Here are some notes from the developer who found this error: In previous versions of MVC, the ActionFilter has the same lifetime as the controller or the action itself: a single web request. In MVC3, the ActionFilter's lifetime was extended so that ActionFilters could be cached for performance reasons. Since MVC3 silently extended the lifetime of the filter, the service reference may not be bound again for a new request, causing the page to reference a data context that is no longer valid, or populated with cached data that is no longer correct.